# Da erro ao executar esta pagina

Tags: java, android, jdbc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.message.*;
import org.json.*;



public class ver extends Activity {


TextView tvnome;
TextView tvgenero;
TextView tvautonomia;
TextView tvmedicamentos;
TextView txtCreatedAt;
CheckBox chkfemenino;
CheckBox chkmasculino;
CheckBox chkautonomo;
CheckBox chkdependente;
CheckBox chkacamado;
CheckBox chktipo1;
CheckBox chktipo2;
CheckBox chkparkinson;
CheckBox chkalzeimer;
CheckBox chkcoracao;
CheckBox chkavc;
CheckBox chkoutra;
TextView tvoutra;
Button btnEditar;
Button btnVoltar;


String pid;
String id;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 

// single product url
private static final String url_idoso_detalhes = "http://robilaks.byethost11.com/psi/htdocs/get_product_details.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_IDOSO = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";
private static final String TAG_GENERO = "genero";
private static final String TAG_AUTONOMIA = "autonomia";
private static final String TAG_DIABETES = "diabetes";
private static final String TAG_PARKINSON = "parkinson";
private static final String TAG_ALZEIMER = "alzeimer";
private static final String TAG_AVC = "avc";
private static final String TAG_OUTRAO = "outrao";
private static final String TAG_OUTRA = "outra";
private static final String TAG_MEDICAMENTOS = "medicamentos";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ver);
    new GetProductDetails().execute();
    // save button
    btnEditar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);
    btnVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);


    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();
    tvnome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvnome);
    tvmedicamentos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvmedicamentos);
    chkfemenino = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkfemenino);
    chkmasculino = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkmasculino);
    chkautonomo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkautonomo);
    chkdependente = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkdependente);
    chkacamado = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkacamado);

    chktipo1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chktipo1);
    chktipo2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chktipo2);

    chkparkinson = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkparkinson);
    chkalzeimer = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkalzeimer);
    chkcoracao = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkcoracao);
    chkavc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkavc);
    chkoutra = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkoutra);
    tvoutra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvoutra);

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
    id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
    //new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnEditar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new product activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editar.class);

            /*  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ver.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Um Momento...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();*/
                i.putExtra(TAG_PID, id);                
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });


    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new product activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), consultas.class);
                i.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });



}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ver.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("A carregar dados...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_idoso_detalhes, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) { 
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_IDOSO); // JSON Array
                            Log.d("Single Product Dssseeeetails", productObj.toString());
                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                            int genero = Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_GENERO));
                            int autonomia = Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_AUTONOMIA));
                            int diabetes =Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_DIABETES));
                            int parkinson =Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_PARKINSON));
                            int alzeimer =Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_ALZEIMER));
                            int avc =Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_AVC));
                            int outrao =Integer.valueOf(product.getString(TAG_OUTRAO));

                            int generofem = 1;
                            int generomasc = 2;                 
                            int aautonomo = 1;
                            int adependente = 2;
                            int aacamado = 3;
                            int tipo1 = 1;
                            int tipo2 = 2;
                            int pparkinson = 1;
                            int palzeimer = 1;
                            int pavc = 1;
                            int poutrao = 1;
                            // display product data in EditText
                            if(genero == generofem){

                                chkfemenino.setEnabled(false);      
                                chkmasculino.setEnabled(false);
                                chkfemenino.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(genero == generomasc){
                                chkmasculino.setEnabled(false);     
                                chkfemenino.setEnabled(false);
                                chkmasculino.setChecked(true);
                            }

                            if(autonomia == aautonomo){
                                chkautonomo.setEnabled(false);      
                                chkdependente.setEnabled(false);
                                chkacamado.setEnabled(false);
                                chkautonomo.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            if(autonomia == adependente){
                                chkdependente.setEnabled(false);        
                                chkautonomo.setEnabled(false);
                                chkacamado.setEnabled(false);
                                chkdependente.setChecked(true);
                            }

                            if(autonomia == aacamado){
                                chkacamado.setEnabled(false);       
                                chkdependente.setEnabled(false);
                                chkautonomo.setEnabled(false);
                                chkacamado.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        if(diabetes == tipo1){  
                                chktipo1.setEnabled(false);
                                chktipo1.setChecked(true);
                            }

                            if(diabetes == tipo2){  
                                chktipo2.setEnabled(false);
                                chktipo2.setChecked(true);
                            }

                            if(parkinson == pparkinson){    
                                chkparkinson.setEnabled(false);

                                chkparkinson.setChecked(true);

                            }

                            if(alzeimer == palzeimer){  
                                chkalzeimer.setEnabled(false);

                                chkalzeimer.setChecked(true);

                            }
                            if(avc == pavc){    
                                chkavc.setEnabled(false);
                                chkavc.setChecked(true);
                            }

                            if(outrao == poutrao){  
                                chkoutra.setEnabled(false);
                                chkoutra.setChecked(true);
                                tvoutra.setText(product.getString(TAG_OUTRA));
                            }
                            tvnome.setText(product.getString(TAG_NOME));
                            tvmedicamentos.setText(product.getString(TAG_MEDICAMENTOS));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Provavelmente um ou mais atributos do produto estão vindo nulos `(JSONObject product)`, com isso você terá uma exceção deste tipo em `Integer.valueOf(null)`.

[]'s

Comment: eu vi no php e vem tudo bem

Comment: Na tela é possível ver os atributos nulos (log "Single Product Dssseeeetails"). É possível que a requisição não esteja saindo da mesma forma que é feita no seu PHP. 

Verifique se o "params" tem o mesmo conteúdo que é passado na requisição PHP.

Comment: Oi Vasco, quando tiver um retorno me avise. []'s